# batch if loop not able to execute

Tags: sql, batch-file

iam trying to put if loops in batch script but not getting desired result, please look into code ans suggest where iam wrong in if loop
 IF  %banned% == 1  echo "vvvvv" it not comparing properly
even 1==1 and 1==0 is same for batch script?

```
    call E:\utility\batfiles\DBAEnvProd.cmd
set dbname=UMRdb

set proc=UMRdb.[dbo].[maintenancemode] 
call %osqlExeLocation% -E -d%dbname% -S%svr% -w%w% -b -Q"exec %proc%" -o%pathout%%Maintmode.txt

@echo on
set "usrname=Y"
set "banfile=E:\utility\sysout\Maintmode.txt"
find /i "%usrname%" "%banfile%" >nul 2>&1&&set /a banned=1 || set /a banned=0
echo %banned%
echo comparing maintenance

IF  %banned% == 1  echo "vvvvv"
(
```

here banned is 1 then i dont want to execute rest of code it shd 
go to endgood
)

else
normal code should be executed

```
@echo on
REM ********************************************************************************
REM JOB: TCMP_DBA_M_MNT_UMR_ESSENTIAL
REM 
REM ********************************************************************************

set job=TCMP_DBA_M_MNT_UMR_ESSENTIAL
set RetCode=0
time /T & date /T

erase %pathout%%job%*.suc > nul
erase %patherr%%job%*.err > nul

REM ********************************************************************************
REM to display date and time
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:. " %%A in ('time/T') do set var=%%A%%B%%C%
set timestamp=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%
set timestamp1=%timestamp%%var%
REM
REM ********************************************************************************

:main

echo --- DB Growth Info
set proc=UMRdb.[dbo].[spCollectDBSpaceInfo] 
call %osqlExeLocation% -E -d%dbname% -S%svr% -w%w% -b -Q"exec %proc%" -o%pathout%%job%_spCollectDBSpaceInfo.txt
if errorlevel 1 (
    set RetCode=1
    goto endbad
)

echo --- Cleanup of output files older than 30 days in sysout folder 
call forfiles -p E:\utility\sysout /D -30 /M *.txt /C "cmd /c del @file" 






:ENDGOOD
set RetCode=0
ECHO SUCCESS!!! %svr% %job% %proc% 
echo %ErrMsg% > %pathout%%job%.SUC

GOTO END

:ENDBAD
set RetCode=1  
ECHO ERROR!!! %svr% %job% %proc% 
echo  SEE %pathout%%job%_%proc%.txt FOR ERRORS > %patherr%%job%.ERR

:END
time /T & date /T
echo %RetCode%

%pathexe%cc.exe %RetCode%

REM EXIT
```

Comment: question is very much clear if anyone has doubt please people can ask

Comment: telling us, your question is clear doesn't make it clear. a) `-o%pathout%%Maintmode.txt` What's the double `%%` doing? b) if you want to go to another part of the script, why don't you use `goto`? c) what's th single `(` doing in the line after the suspect `if` (which works fine by the way)?

Answer (score -2):

this is problematic

```
IF  %banned% == 1  echo "vvvvv"
```

if == performs a string comparision and i'm seeing lots of spaces. *if %banned% is 1* here you are comparing " 1" == "1 ". As you set/a banned=1, it would be better do a numeric comparision

```
IF %banned% EQU 1
```

or quoted string comparision

```
If "%banned%" == "1"
```

Comment: indeed, `IF   %banned%  ==  1  echo "vvvvv"` works fine - independent of how many spaces and where they are (although it's bad style).

Comment: iam using what is said but still iam getting error in cmd prompt                                                                                                                               E:\utility\batfiles>echo comparing maintenan
comparing maintenance
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
E:\utility\batfiles>IF  "1" == "1" if 1=1 in strin is incorrect what is correct syntax its simple i just want to compare if it sucessfull it shd execute certain piece ofcode wheewww vbscript is much better

Comment: stephan what can be correct stylei just want to use simple if loop